# Oracle: are the contents of v$session retained anywhere in the database beyond the logged in time of each session id

Tags: oracle, authentication, proxy

Can anyone tell me please is there a table/set of tables that retain the contents of v$session after the session has been completed?

I am asking as I am using client_identifier in v$session to record proxy users in my database using an after login trigger. However, v$session content is not retained and for business audit purposes, I need a long term record of which sessions were created by proxy users and which were created by other access methods.

I know dba_audit_trail includes proxy sessionid, but I don't see how I can track that proxy sessionid back to the identity of the user who has proxied into a particular schema without the client_identifier in v$session.

I'm wondering if I need to build my own table but would like to know if Oracle can do this for me already, before I start duplicating any work.

Thanks

Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle does not retain `v$session` info. You will in fact need to create your own table and use your after logon trigger to populate it. You should key it not only by `inst_id,sid,serial#`, but also by `logon_time`.

Also, if you are interested in proxy, you can use `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','PROXY_USER')` to get the proxy user.

Other `userenv` vars that are useful in a logon trigger and not available in `v$session` include: `DBLINK_INFO`, `AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY`, `AUTHENTICATION_METHOD`. But of course there are plenty of things you'll want from `v$session` as well, which you can retrieve using the SID from `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID')`.